# How can Miller convert a local date and time to UTC?

Tags: csv, utc, gmt, localtime, miller

How can [Miller 5.6.2](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v5.6.2) convert a local date and time to [`UTC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) using an expression simpler than the following?

```
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=sec2gmt(
    localtime2sec(
      strftime(
        strptime($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p"),
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")));'
time1
2019-06-13T10:54:00Z
```

Note that my local time zone in June is `EDT` or `-04:00`:

```
$ date --date='2019-06-13 05:54 PM' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z'
2019-06-13T17:54:00 EDT
$ date --date='2019-06-13 05:54 PM' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
2019-06-13T17:54:00-0400
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two similar expressions, both of which use [`strptime_local()`](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html#strptime_local) instead of [`strptime()`](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html#strptime) to parse the local date and time string and convert it to seconds since the Epoch in UTC (GMT):

```
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strftime(
    strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p"),
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");'
time1
2019-06-13T10:54:00Z
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=sec2gmt(strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p"));'
time1
2019-06-13T10:54:00Z
```

Both [`strftime()`](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html#strftime) and [`sec2gmt()`](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html#sec2gmt) assume an argument of seconds since the Epoch in UTC.

Function `strptime()` assumes an input date and time string in UTC and ignores a time zone in the input string:

```
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p");'
time1
1560405240.000000
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM EDT\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p %Z");'
time1
1560405240.000000
```

Function `strptime_local()` also ignores a time zone in the input date and time string, but assumes the string is in the local time zone and converts it to UTC:

```
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p");'
time1
1560423240.000000
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM EDT\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p %Z");'
time1
1560423240.000000
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM EST\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p %Z");'
time1
1560423240.000000
$ printf "time1\n2019-06-13 05:54 PM AUT\n" | mlr --csv put '
  $time1=strptime_local($time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p %Z");'
time1
1560423240.000000
```

Comment: Turns out that neither of the two expressions in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61876042/2 give the correct result. Date and time `2019-06-13 05:54 PM -0400` actually translates to `2019-06-13 21:54:00 +0000` in UTC (see `date --utc --date="2019-06-13 17:54 -0400" "+%F %T %z"`).